# Bootstrap-select add actions based on selected options using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-selectpicker

I have a [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) and I want to add conditions based on user interaction.

If user opens the dropdown and on close the user :

1. selected different value(s) comparing to the initial value(s) on show, it will alert 'value changed'
2. kept the current value(s) equal to initial value(s) on show, it will alert 'same value'
3. doesn't select any option, it will alert 'no value'

Please find below a simple demo with an explanation. I couldn't figure out it why my logic is not working properly.

What I did is :

I created a global variable `initVal` and on `show.bs.select` event I store the initial value.

Then on `hide.bs.select` event I check if there is/are option(s) selected `val.length > 0` and the value is different to initial value `initVal != val` then alert 'value changed'

Then if again if there is/are option(s) selected `val.length > 0` and the value is equal to initial value `initVal == val` then alert 'same value'

Then if nothing selected `val.length == 0` then alert 'any value'

To see the issue, select for example a country and close the dropdown and open it again. it will show you new value each time. or when a X country is selected, so select other countries then unselect them and before closing keep the same X country and it will not show correct result.

Any suggestions please ? Thank you very much.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

$("select").selectpicker();

// declare global variable to store the initial value of my select
var initVal;

// when the select dropdown opens, store the current value in initVal
$("select").on('show.bs.select', function () {
initVal = $(this).val();
console.log('initial value is ' + initVal);
});

// when the select dropdown is closed, store the current value in val
$("select").on("hide.bs.select", function() {
var val = $(this).val();
console.log('current value is ' + val);

// if the select has at least an option selected AND the current value is different to initial value then show alert new value
if ( (val.length > 0) && (initVal != val) )  {
alert("you selected a new value");  }
//if the select has at least an option selected AND the current value is equal to initial value then show alert same value
else if ( (val.length > 0) && (initVal == val) ) { 
alert("you selected the same value");  }
//if the select hasn't any option selected AND the current value is different to initial value then show alert same value
else if ( val.length == 0 ) { 
alert("no value selected");  }

});


} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.1/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.17/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="form-control show-tick" data-container="body" data-header="Select option(s)" data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true" title="All" data-selected-text-format="count > 0" multiple>
<option>Austria</option>  
<option>Denmark</option>
<option>France</option>  
<option>Japan</option>    
</select>
```

Comment: Currently, you have multiple options selectable. is that what you want?

Comment: @PharsaThapa  right

Comment: I could not understand your question clearly. Can you explain, a bit differently? i believe it is not a hard issue. And i dont see any problems in your codes

Comment: @PharsaThapa  open the dropdown. by default nothing is selected so initial value is empty then select for example Austria and close dropdown. now current value is Austria which is different to initial val, the alert shows 'value changed'.  Now as you selected Austria and dropdown is closed. when you reopen dropdown the initial val is Austria. keep it selected and close dropdown like you didn't make any changes. based on condition there is an option selected and initial val is equal selected value before closing dropdown so alert should be 'same value' but shows ' new value'. is it clear now ?

Comment: I have posted a solution for you in answer section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("select").selectpicker();

// declare global variable to store the initial value of my select
var initVal;

// when the select dropdown opens, store the current value in initVal
$("select").on('show.bs.select', function () {
initVal = $(this).val().toString();
console.log('initial value is ' + initVal);
});

// when the select dropdown is closed, store the current value in val
$("select").on("hide.bs.select", function() {
var val = $(this).val().toString();
console.log('current value is ' + val);


// if the select has at least an option selected AND the current value is different to initial value then show alert new value
if ( initVal !== val )  {
console.log("new");
//alert("you selected a new value");  
}
//if the select has at least an option selected AND the current value is equal to initial value then show alert same value
else if ( initVal === val) { 
console.log("same")
//alert("you selected the same value");  
}
//if the select hasn't any option selected AND the current value is different to initial value then show alert same value
else if ( val.length == 0 ) { 
console.log("none")
//alert("no value selected");  
}

});


} );
```

Your HTML as it is.